# Doctrine: extra where on relation (many-to-many)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

This is my first question ever so I hope I do everything how it should.

I have 2 doctrine entities with a many-to-many relationship and that works fine but I also would like to add an extra check on the many-to-many table. The problem is that in DQL I can not get to the right column.

I have thought of 2 possibilities: abstract parent class or native query.
I will paste the native query that works below but it isn't what I was hoping for because we will have to copy and paste it.

**So I want to make the relation + the type. so for this example I also need to check for type = 'Gallery'**

gallery_object (Table)
id, tag, deleted
1, sponsors, 0

media_relations (Table)
id, mediaid, type, typeId
1, 37, gallery, 1

media_files
id, userid, filename, filepath, filesize, mime_type, date, deleted
37, 4, 533882_10151332524797037_1940030593_n_20.jpg, /resources/upload/www/, 82724, image/jpeg, 2013-01-25 15:04:46, 0

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult(Helper::getNamespace('Gallery', 'Models/Entities') . "Object", 'o')
    ->addFieldResult('o', 'id', 'id')
    ->addFieldResult('o', 'tag', 'tag')
    ->addFieldResult('o', 'deleted', 'deleted')
    ->addJoinedEntityResult(ltrim(Helper::getNamespace('Media', 'Models/Entities') . "Media", '\\'), 'm', 'o', 'file')
    ->addFieldResult('o', 'file', 'id')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'mid', 'id')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'user', 'userid')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'filename', 'filename')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'filepath', 'filepath')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'filesize', 'filesize')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'mime_type', 'mime_type')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'date', 'date')
    ->addFieldResult('m', 'mdeleted', 'deleted');

$sql = "SELECT o.id AS oid, m.id as file, o.tag, o.deleted, m.id AS mid, m.userid, m.filename, m.filepath, m.filesize, m.mime_type, m.date, m.deleted as mdeleted
    FROM gallery_object as o
        INNER JOIN media_relations mr ON (mr.typeid = o.id AND mr.type = 'Gallery')
        INNER JOIN media_files m ON (mr.mediaid = m.id)";
$result = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)->getResult();

return $result;
```

The entities look like

```
/**
 * Media entity
 *
 * @Entity(repositoryClass = "iTet\Application\Modules\Media\Models\Repositories\Media")
 * @Table(name="media_files")
 * @author Stephen Fenne
 */

class Media
{
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue
 * @var int
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="iTet\Application\Modules\Core\User\Models\Entities\User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @var int
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @Column(length = 100)
 * @var string
 */
protected $filename;

/**
 * @Column
 * @var string
 */
protected $filepath;

/**
 * @Column(type = "integer")
 * @var int
 */
protected $filesize;

/**
 * @Column
 * @var string
 */
protected $mime_type;

/**
 * @Column(type = "datetime", nullable=true)
 * @var \DateTime 
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @Column(type = "integer")
 * @var int
 */
protected $deleted = false;
```

--

```
/**
 *
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="iTet\Application\Modules\Gallery\Models\Repositories\Object")
 * @Table(name="gallery_object")
 * @author Ward Peeters <ward@coding-tech.com>
 * @package
 */
class Object
{
/** @Id
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue
 * @var int */
protected $id;
/** @ManyToMany(targetEntity="iTet\Application\Modules\Media\Models\Entities\Media")
 * @JoinTable(name="media_relations",
 *   joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="typeid", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="mediaid", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @var Media */
protected $file;
/** @Column
 * @var string */
protected $tag;
/** @Column(type="integer")
 * @var bool */
protected $deleted = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, your options are the following:

1. Introduce an entity to represent entries in the `media_relations` table, plus the appropriate associations with other tables.
2. Introduce a 'media relations' hierarchy via class-table inheritance (to model the different 'types') and query only on 'Gallery' types. [Doctrine inheritance documentation.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

In both cases you'd then expose the underlying table to Doctrine such that you can use DQL to get at the data you need.

HTH

Comment: I also think that is the best way to do it but I think the second one is cleaner. I thought maybe there was something I didn't see in the documentation but I guess it has to be like this.